# Install nmap 7 on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, compile

Since nmap 7 is not yet in the official ubuntu repos I tryed to install nmap like mentioned on the nmap install guide:

```
wget https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.00-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo alien nmap-7.00-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i nmap_7.00-2_amd64.deb
```

Everything exits successfully, but:

```
~$ nmap
bash: /usr/local/bin/nmap: File or Folder not found
```

but:

```
~$ ndiff
/usr/bin/ndiff: need exactly two input filenames.
Try '/usr/bin/ndiff -h' for help.
```

so I apt-get removed it and tryed to build from source:

```
wget https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.00.tar.bz2
bzip2 -cd nmap-7.00.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
cd nmap-7.00
./configure

"Configured with: ndiff zenmap nping openssl lua ncat"
"Configured without: localdirs nmap-update"

make
sudo make install

"NPING SUCCESSFULLY INSTALLED"
"NMAP SUCCESSFULLY INSTALLED"
```

Wich is true, but zenmap is not correctly installed:

```
~$ zenmap
"[Errno 2] File or Folder not found: '/usr/share/zenmap/config"
```

Wich is true, /usr/share/zenmap does not exist and I cannot find any command in the install output which writes anything to /usr/share...

And ndiff is not installed at all:

```
~$ ndiff
"bash: /usr/bin/ndiff: File or folder not found"
```

Here are some informations about my system:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux python 4.2.0-11-generic #13-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 21:33:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```